# How to remove leading "0." in a numeric R variable

Tags: r, formatting, decimal

How can one concisely change a numeric R variable (keeping it numeric) so that, e.g., 
"-0.34" becomes simply "-.34"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Only when you output a numeric value do you have to choose a concrete representation (i.e., how the number should be formatted).  You cannot change a numeric variable from "-0.34" to "-.34"; both are representations for the same number.

However, when you output an expression `e`, you can choose how it should be formatted.  I don't know of any build-in way to leave off the leading "0", but you could always just remove it manually:

```
> sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", -0.34))
[1] "-.34"
```

You can define a function for convenience, e.g.,

```
numformat <- function(val) { sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", val)) }
```

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the existing answers, I wanted to mention that the package `weights` has a function `rd()` which can be used to "round numbers to text with no leading zero". Of course, the result is not numeric but character.

```
library("weights")
rd(-0.341, digits=2)
[1] "-.34"
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to show numbers to 3 decimal places.
If you want to print to an arbitrary number of decimal places and you don't want to have to add another package (i.e., the `weights` package above), then this function (adapted from @stefan's answer) seems to work:

```
numformat <- function(x, digits = 2) { 
    ncode <- paste0("%.", digits, "f")
    sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf(ncode, x))
}
```

So for example:

```
> numformat(-.232, 2)
[1] "-.23"
> numformat(-.232, 3)
[1] "-.232"
> numformat(-.232, 4)
[1] "-.2320"
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's for reporting in R Markdown I use the package MOTE with the function apa() and code: `apa(-0.34, 2, FALSE)` this will return -.34 in my documents.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @stefan's nice answer, I stumbled upon the following code which accomplishes the same thing but prints out more decimal places:

```
f = function(X1)gsub("0\\.","\\.", X1)
```

Comment: You need to be careful about just replacing "0." with ".", as this will turn "10.12" into "1.12", which is presumably not intended.  I solved this by using the regular expression `"^(-?)0."`.  This only matches if the zero is the first character (except possibly a `-`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Stefan.  @Manoel Galdino - for me the variable remains numeric after using Stefan's function.