# gsub and pad inside of a parenthesis

Tags: r

I have  vector like this:

```
x <- c("20(0.23)", "15(0.2)", "16(0.09)")
```

and I don't want to mess with the numbers on the outside of the parenthesis but want to remove the leading zero on the numbers inside and make everything have 2 digits.  The output will look like:

```
"20(.23)", "15(.20)", "16(.09)"
```

**Useful information:**

I can remove leading zero and retain 2 digits using the function below taken from: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643391/how-to-remove-leading-0-in-a-numeric-r-variable)

```
numformat <- function(val) { sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", val)) }

numformat(c(0.2, 0.26))
#[1] ".20" ".26"
```

I know `gsub` can be used but I don't know how.  I'll provide a `strsplit` answer but that's hackish at best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gsubfn package allows you to replace anything matched by a regex with a function applied  to the match.  So we could use what you have with your `numformat` function

```
library(gsubfn)
# Note that I added as.numeric in because what will be passed in
# is a character string
numformat <- function(val){sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(val)))}
gsubfn("0\\.\\d+", numformat, x)
#[1] "20(.23)" "15(.20)" "16(.09)"
```

Comment: Wow that was pretty nicely done.  This just convinced me to learn the `gsubfn` package.

Comment: To be honest this is the first time I've ever used `gsubfn` so it could probably be done even cleaner than this.  But I vaguely recalled that gsubfn lets you replace stuff with functions acting on that stuff so this seemed like the perfect reason to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
pad.fix<-function(x){
y<-gsub('\\.(\\d)\\)','\\.\\10\\)',x)
gsub('0\\.','\\.',y)
}
```

the first gsub adds a trailing zero if needed the second gsub removes the leading zero.

Answer (score 2):

That is yet another of these Tyler questions that seem to be complicated just for complications sake :)

So here you go:

```
R> x <- c("20(0.23)", "15(0.2)", "16(0.09)")
R> sapply(strsplit(gsub("^(\\d+)\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1 \\2", x), " "), 
+         function(x) sprintf("%2d(.%02d)", 
+                              as.numeric(x[1]), 
+                              as.numeric(x[2])*100))
[1] "20(.23)" "15(.20)" "16(.09)"
R>
```

We do a few things here:

1. The `gsub()` picks off the two two numbers: first the one before the parens, then the one inside the parens. [With hindsight, should have picked after the decimal, see below.]
2. This prints them out just with whitespace, e.g. `"20 0.23"` for the first.
3. We then use a standard `strsplit()` on this.
4. We then use `sapply` to process the list we get from `strsplit`
5. We print the first number as a two-digit int.
6. The second one is more tricky -- the `(s)printf()` family *cannot* suppress a leading zero so we print the decimal, and the print two digits of an integer -- and convert the second number accordingly.

It is all concise and in one line, but it would be clearer broken out.

**Edit:** I don;t often provide the fastest solutions, but when I do, at least I can gloat:

```
R> dason <- function(x) { numformat <- function(val){sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(val)))}; gsubfn("0\\.\\d+", numformat, x) }
R> dirk <- function(x) { sapply(strsplit(gsub("^(\\d+)\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1 \\2", x), " "), function(x) sprintf("%2d(.%02d)", as.numeric(x[1]), as.numeric(x[2])*100)) }
R> 
R> dason(x)
[1] "20(.23)" "15(.20)" "16(.09)"
R> dirk(x)
[1] "20(.23)" "15(.20)" "16(.09)"
R> 
R> res <- benchmark(dason(x), dirk(x), replications=1000, order="relative")
R> res
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2  dirk(x)         1000   0.133    1.000     0.132    0.000          0         0
1 dason(x)         1000   2.026   15.233     1.960    0.064          0         0
R>
```

So that's about 15 rimes faster. Not that it matters in *this* context, but speed never hurt anyone in the long run.

Comment: Oh Dirk you love complication, it makes life fun :) +1

Comment: Sure thing, especially when we can solve issues old-school with just base R and without any of these newfangled packages. :)

Comment: My solution runs circles around Dason's. Edit coming.

Answer (score 0):

Non `gsub` answer that's ugly at best.

```
x <- c("20(0.23)", "15(0.2)", "16(0.09)")

numformat <- function(val) { sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", val)) }
z <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("\\)", "", x), "\\("))
z[, 2] <- numformat(as.numeric(z[, 2]))
paste0(z[, 1], "(", z[, 2], ")")
```