# How to make a vector-to-object lookup/hash table?

Tags: r, hashmap

I want to store an object with a number vector as key in some data structure, such that I can later retrieve that object when I supply the data structure with an identical vector. How can I do that?

All vectors have the same number of elements. The number of objects that will be stored is low (<20).

Something like:

```
hash[c(1,2,4)] <- myObject
```

Comment: Andreas, I have found that when I can't provide a reproducible example (a how to question) it's helpful to provide a before and after data set of what you're after.  Here's an example of where I provided a sample input and output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876820/gsub-and-pad-inside-of-a-parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `list` and turn your vector key into a unique character key, using `paste` for example:

```
hash <- list()
hash[[paste(c(1,2,4), collapse = '.')]] <- 1:10
hash
# $`1.2.4`
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Same idea for retrieving the object:

```
hash[[paste(c(1,2,4), collapse = '.')]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```