# format numeric without leading zero

Tags: r

What's the best way to format a numeric so that it does NOT show leading zero. For example:

```
test = .006
sprintf/format/formatC( ??? )  # should result in ".006"
```

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643391/how-to-remove-leading-0-in-a-numeric-r-variable) to a related question useful. It uses base R and does not drop leading digits that are not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always fix it up yourself with regular expression search-and-replace:

```
library(stringr)
test = .006
str_replace(as.character(test), "^0\\.", ".")
```

Not the most elegant answer, but it works. Substitute whatever string conversion you like for `as.character`, such as `sprintf` with your preferred floating point format.

Comment: you could use `sub` instead of `stringr`.

Comment: stringr is nice for some things but I see it used too often when the base function would work just as well...

Comment: Yes, but stringr has a consistent interface and sane defaults, so I chose to learn the stringr functions instead of trying to memorize the base R ones. Feel free to use your preferred regular expression substitution function.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I answered this once before but can't find it.  You *cannot* tell `sprintf()` et al about a format that drops the leading zero ... so you have to do it yourself, eg via `substring()`:

```
R> val <- 0.006
R> aa <- substring(sprintf("%4.3f", val), 2)
R> aa
[1] ".006"
R>
```

Comment: thanks Dirk!  good answer.  Accepting Ryan's because it generalizes for any number of significant digits

Comment: So just do `substring(as.character(val), 2)` which does not need anything but base R, and is likely "faster" (not that it matters) than a regexp solution.

Comment: that doesn't work when there are digits to the left of decimal like 2.22

Comment: Well that wasn't part of your "specification" in question above so it's a tad hard for me to guestimate the need. I gave you an efficient answer for the question you asked...

Comment: This works nicely on a single column of a data frame; but it will not work for 2 or more columns of a data frame simultaneously.  For instance, supposing 'val' in the above example is a data frame with 3 columns and some number of rows, I can get val[,1] to work; but val[,1:2] throws the error '(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double''.  Any suggestions on how to apply this function to a data frame, where all variables are numeric?

Answer (score 2):

```
f <- function(x) gsub("^(\\s*[+|-]?)0\\.", "\\1.", as.character(x))
f(0.006)
# ".006"
f(-0.006)
# "-.006"
f("+0.006")
# "+.006"
f(" 0.006")
# " .006"
f(10.05)
# "10.05"
```

Comment: This should be the answer as it handles the main use cases and uses base r.