# How get rid of the numbers before the decimal in a shiny datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I scraped a table from a website and want to show the table in a shiny app. The shiny app has statistics where I want the numbers to show in a format of '.###'. Instead, they are showing as '#.###' I have tried many functions like formatRound, sprintf, sub, and have changed the datatypes accordingly. But I have not managed to get the right format that I want. Any suggestions?

I want the numbers to show as .333 instead of 0.333

Here is an example:

```r
scrape <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)
  table_nodes <- html_nodes(page, "table")
  desired_table <- html_table(table_nodes)[[1]]
  
  return (desired_table)
}
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(shiny)
library(weights)
library(DT)


ui<- fluidPage(
      mainPanel(       
        DT::DTOutput('y')    
    ))


server <-function(input,output){
  
  output$y<- DT::renderDT({
    
    star <- scrape("https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/leader.cgi?type=bat&id=862d7729")
    stars<-star%>%
      transmute(Name,
                x=as.numeric(BA),
                y=as.numeric(OBP),
                z=as.numeric(SLG))
      
    datatable(stars, selection = 'multiple',
              options =list(pageLength=50))%>% 
      formatRound(c(2:4), digits=3)
        
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Is this R? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643391/how-to-remove-leading-0-in-a-numeric-r-variable

Comment: @HEllRZA Yes, this is R.

Comment: then follow the link ;)

Comment: @guasi I used this source and tried to add the sub() function in a mutate to my variables and it didn’t work. It still shows as “#.###’.

Comment: @HEllRZA I used this source and tried to add the sub() function in a mutate to my variables and it didn’t work. It still shows as “#.###’.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solutions posted here [How to remove leading "0." in a numeric R variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643391/how-to-remove-leading-0-in-a-numeric-r-variable)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(shiny)
library(weights)
library(DT)

scrape <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)
  table_nodes <- html_nodes(page, "table")
  desired_table <- html_table(table_nodes)[[1]]
  
  return (desired_table)
}

ui<- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(       
    DT::DTOutput('y')    
  ))


server <-function(input,output){
  
  output$y <- DT::renderDT({
    
    star  <- scrape("https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/leader.cgi?type=bat&id=862d7729")
    stars <- star %>%
      transmute(Name,
                x = sub("^(-?)0\\.","\\.",as.character(BA)),
                y = sub("^(-?)0\\.","\\.",as.character(OBP)),
                z = sub("^(-?)0\\.","\\.",as.character(SLG)))
    datatable(stars, selection = 'multiple',
              options =list(pageLength=50)) 
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: I run that and my data table says, "No data available in table". Any other suggestions?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the entire app. It contains the same code chunk I posted earlier using the solution posted in the link. I get no errors, it runs and values display without leading zero.

Comment: is there I can filter by a variable after this code? For example: after the options argument, I use a pipe '%>%' and filter(SLG >.450) ??

Comment: The solution here and in the link offer you the line of code that you need to achieve your desired format. You can adapt it to your needs. Do the string substitution after you process the data and do all your filtering, as the formatting will convert the values to character type. You can do the string substitution in the last step of your processing, the step right before passing the dataframe to `datatable()`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was able to get the result that I wanted. However, when I add a filter() in the last line. It gives me an error again. Are you suggesting I add filter() before the datatable function?

Comment: No, you probably want to filter before the vectors get turned to character type. I would remove the string substitution from where it's at right now, do your filtering, then after do the string substitution. Transforming the vectors to character should be your last step.